# Adding data columns in AWS Glue

Tags: aws-glue

I couldn't find a fitting sub community so I hope that my question fits in here.

I am currently working on setting up an ETL pipeline for an analytics solution on AWS using S3, Lambda, Redshift, and Glue. Doing this I stumbled onto a use case I believed was usual but I haven't found much about it on google at all.

My problem is that I have been pulling in data from a third party source for a couple of months before discovering that I am missing a couple of columns that would be good to have. During the initial setup it was no big problem to just reset everything and reload everything with a new data table (both in glue and in redshift) but this would cost a significant amount of money to do at this point.

What would be a good way of adding a data column to an existing data table in the Glue data catalog without creating an entirely new table? I could manage with just empty (or NULL) values for the preexisting rows.

Many thanks!

Comment: If you have Athena integrated with Glue data catalog then you can simply use "Alter table add columns" statement in Athena to add new column to table.

Comment: Unfortunately no access to Athena. Is there any way to solve this with onot the services mentioned in my initial post?

Answer (score 5):

You can add column to an existing table in Glue data catalog using any of below two options

1. The first option is to manually change on the glue console going to Databases -> Tables -> Click table -> Edit Schema -> Add column. You should be able to see it in your table once it is updated.
2. If you don't want to do manually then you can make use of [Glue API call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-catalog-tables.html#aws-glue-api-catalog-tables-UpdateTable) by selecting your choice of programming language. For example python for [Boto3 API call](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.update_table).